# Keep page loading until map is finished

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, array.prototype.map

I have the following code, where I fetch an API and populate a container inside a function

```js
let forms = [];

fetch('http://localhost:3000/getmenu')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        forms = favorites = data;
        showForms(forms);
    })
    .catch(console.log('catch'));
  
 function showForms(arrayForms) {
container.innerHTML = '';
arrayForms.map(
({ NUMERO, DESCRICAO, GRUPO, AUDIT_DATA }) => {
  container.innerHTML = `foo`
}
```

However, the page loads extremely fast but the results take a few seconds to show up.
How can I keep the page in the loading state until the funciton is complete?

Comment: are you using react?

Comment: The question here is: why do you want to "keep the page in the loading state"? Do you have other stuff that happens when the page is loaded? Are you using window.onload? Why not simply run that stuff in your showForms function instead?

Comment: @ChrisG Because I have other functions that also depend on fetch, I just ommited them for this example. Do you think .onload would help ?

Comment: So you are loading a bunch of stuff using multiple fetch commands, and you want to display a loader until all of them have finished? Is that the actual question?

Comment: No. I only have one fetch which is the one above. But since the API is very big, the arrayForms.map takes a while to display all the results. I want the page to keep loading until the results show up on the screen.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "I want the page to keep loading"? This means absolutely nothing to me.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the page to keep its loading state so I can use the load event when it stops loading

Comment: Yes, but which load event? What code are you using to handle this load event?

Comment: window.addEventListener('load', () => {foo}); As I mentioned, this triggers very quickly exactly because the page loads very quickly. And after the page loads, the map function still runs for a couple of seconds because it is running through all the API results and displaying them in li's

Comment: So in other words, you *are* using window.onload. Anyway, whatever you have in there, you simply need to run it after the .map() call instead.

Comment: I did but for some reason what i call after the map also runs before

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
arrayForms ? arrayForms.map(
({ NUMERO, DESCRICAO, GRUPO, AUDIT_DATA }) => {
  container.innerHTML = `foo`
}) : "Loading data..."
```

Answer (score 0):

SO I simply used a ternary operator after the map like so

```js
container.innerHTML == '' ? console.log('not yet') : console.log('now');
```

which reads when the map has finished. This bypasses a problem I was having where a line after map() is also be executed before map().